# How to eager load featured_media, categories and author along with the post with WP-API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wp-api

Is it possible to eager load featured_media, categories and author information along with the post data with wp-api. I've checked the docs (http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) and can't find any information on it.

I'm coming from a PHP background, specifically Laravel, and they offer Eager/Lazy Loading with their Eloquent methods https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading